# Nginx Container: no "ssl_certificate_key" is defined for certificate

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-registry

I am trying to run a private docker registry using this [tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-a-private-docker-registry). But after I did everything and run the docker-compose, I get the following error from the `nginx` container

> no "ssl_certificate_key" is defined for certificate
> "/home/user/registry/nginx/ssl/key.pem"

Here is the registry.conf file:

```
upstream docker-registry {
    server registry:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name privatesecurereg.netspan.com;

    ssl_certificate /home/user/registry/nginx/ssl/csr.pem;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/registry/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

    # Log files for Debug
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        # Do not allow connections from docker 1.5 and earlier
        # docker pre-1.6.0 did not properly set the user agent on ping, catch "Go *" user agents
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "^(docker\/1\.(3|4|5(?!\.[0-9]-dev))|Go ).*$" )  {
            return 404;
        }

        proxy_pass                          http://docker-registry;
        proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout                  900;
    }

}
```

What is the rpobelom and how to fix it ?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my docker-compose:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
    networks:
      - mynet
```

Comment: Replace `ssl_certificate /home/user/registry/nginx/ssl/key.pem;` with `ssl_certificate_key /home/user/registry/nginx/ssl/key.pem;`

Comment: @saeed : No success as I get: `failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/home/user/registry/nginx/ssl/csr.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)` !!

Comment: I am wondering if my `.pem` files are not correct. How can I properly generate these files mentioned in step 5 of the tutorial ?!

Comment: How did you generate them? You can use `certbot` which is Let's Encrypt Certificate. Did you try that or you don't want that? You also can check your certificates validity at `sslshopper.com` website

Comment: @Saeed : I was generating the wrong `.pem` file that starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----` where it should start with only `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` . I tried to use `certbot` but failed. I had to regenerate the certificate manually using `openssl` command. Now it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had missed something in `docker-compose` file. This is working sample we use.

```
nginx:
  image: "nginx:alpine"
  ports:
    - 5000:443
  links:
    - registry:registry
  volumes:
    - ./auth:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./auth/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

registry:
  image: registry:2.7.0
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/registry
```

Keep an eye on this part

```
volumes:
    - ./auth:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./auth/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

Here `auth` folder has certificate and key file. Also httpd file for docker registry login.

In `nginx.conf` we directly refered inside the `nginx` container.

```
# SSL
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/csr.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/csr.key;
```

Answer (score 4):

You mount your certificate dir `/home/user/registry/nginx/ssl/` to `/etc/nginx/ssl` in docker

Therefore in nginx config you need to use ssl files under `/etc/nginx/ssl` change `fullchain.pem` or `privkey.pem` if needed, btw this is from the tutorial try to follow it

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;
```

Comment: Yes. It was `/etc/ngnix/ssl/` but I chnaged it thinking it wasn't mounted correctly. But I didn't chnaged it back afterward. Now I put the right path, I get this error: `cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/csr.pem": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)` .. !!

Comment: under `./nginx/ssl` run `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privkey.key -out cert.crt` and change nginx config to `ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;` and `ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;` 
`