# Docker Registry behind HAProxy not working properly

Tags: docker, haproxy, docker-registry

I have configured Docker Registry using htpasswd authentication as docker service. I use a port mapping 443:5000 and it works perfectly. "docker login :443" works, "docker pull <mydomain:433/myimage" works.

The container service looks like this:

```
 myhub:
    image: myhub
    ports:
        - "443:5000"
    environment:
        - REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000
        - REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/efimeridopolis.privkey.pem
        - REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/efimeridopolis.fullchain.pem
        - REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd
        - REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM='Registry Realm'
        - REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/registry.htpasswd
    volumes:
        - /mnt/volume1/hub:/var/lib/registry
    networks:
        - myoverlay
```

Now, I try to put it behind HAProxy. SSL is terminated at HAProxy, so the service looks like:

```
myhub:
    image: myhub       
    environment:
        - REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000           
        - REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd
        - REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM='Registry Realm'
        - REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/registry.htpasswd
    volumes:
        - /mnt/volume1/hub:/var/lib/registry
    networks:
        - myoverlay
```

and the relevant part of HAProxy configuration is:

```
frontend fe_443
  mode http
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.pem
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }

  acl host_registry hdr(host) -i hub.mydomain
  use_backend be_registry_443 if host_registry 
backend be_registry_443
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  server hub1 myhub:5000 check
```

It seems something is going wrong here. While accessing

https://hub.mydomain/v2/_catalog

through browser works, which means I am asked for username/password and then I get the list or repositories, when I try to use the console to:

```
$ docker pull hub.mydomain:443/v2/myhaproxy
```

it gives me:

*Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable*

The same when I try:

```
$ docker login mydomain:443
```

I am asked username and password but then I get the same 503 message.

Since browser can list the repositories, I know the registry is online and accessible.

What is wrong ?

Comment: This is related to nginx, but you may get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211110/nginx-container-no-ssl-certificate-key-is-defined-for-certificate/69212350#69212350

Comment: Are you suggesting that HAProxy is missing the certificates ? I think this can't be possible since I can list the repositories through HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

https (443 port) should be tcp mode and using req.ssl_sni instead hdr(host).